# Implementing the factorial rule

Tags: function-construction, recursion

I want to implement a command in Mathematica in order to simplify factorials in the following way

$$(n+x)!=(n+x)(n+x-1)\cdots n!$$

I started to build this up slowly. I have managed to implement

$$(n+x)!=(n+x)(n+x-1)!$$

in the following way

```
factorialproperty[function_] := # (# - 1)! &@function
(p + 3) // factorialproperty
```

And then I thought, to use this in a NestWhile to iterate the procedure, however, I have not managed to make it work. What I tried to do is the following

```
fctrl[function_] := 
 Module[{a = function}, 
  NestWhile[a, Product[(# - i)! &@a, {i, 0, 100}], a >= 0]]
```

And when I tried

```
(p + 3) // factorialproperty
```

I got the wrong result. I thought that I am telling Mma to do the product starting with a, a number of times (I chose i to be 100 because I will never have to compute something higher than that), until applying the product gives negative values, but clearly I have some mistake.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
transform = (a_ + x_Integer/;x>=1)! -> Pochhammer[a+1,x]*a!;
(p + 3)! /. transform
```

> (1 + p) (2 + p) (3 + p) p!

This also works on more general expressions:

```
(p + q + 3)! /. transform
```

> (1 + p + q) (2 + p + q) (3 + p + q) (p + q)!

```
(Sqrt[2] + 3)! /. transform
```

> (1 + Sqrt[2]) (2 + Sqrt[2]) (3 + Sqrt[2]) Sqrt[2]!

Answer (score 2):

You could start with something like this:

```
expandFactorial[expr_] := ReplaceRepeated[expr, (x_Symbol + i_Integer)! :> (x + i) (x + i - 1)!];

expandFactorial[(p + 3)!]
```

> > (1 + p) (2 + p) (3 + p) p!